# Will a HTML Database of a remote Site embedded in UIWebView get cleared when an application update happens?

Tags: ios, database, html, uiwebview

I am experimenting with embedding my pure offline mobile HTML5 ebook reader (http://www.hyper-books.com/) into a UIWebView. Why? I want to see if I can hand off certain heavy duty work to native iOS, lock the orientation of site through the application container, entirely get rid off the status bar and integrate with the twitter framework.

The application is storing all the data in a html5 database. So the following issue crossed my mind: Will the html5 database associated with the UIWebView be flushed if an application update happens on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The database cache is stored in the Library/Caches folder, which is preserved when an app is updated (unless the user deletes the app before updating).